# Dynamically overriding __functions__ in Python

Tags: python

Let's say I want to override a function like `__int__` in a Python class so that I may do something like this.

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__int__ = lambda: 1

a = A()
print int(a)
```

I expect that it would output "1" here instead of produce this error message

> TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'A'

When `__int__` instead becomes a method built into the class it works as expected. Why? (This problem exists with any of the double underscore functions also)

Comment: re: duplicate, the subject matter is similar, but this is a much more concise and general version of the question

Comment: Yes, but the answer is the same.

Comment: Quick answer: You can't. Not so quick answer: Why would want to?

Comment: Curiosity. I was playing around with a design idea in a project and came across this problem. It confused me so I asked. Isn't that was SO is for?

Comment: @Mike: No, that's perfectly fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That appears to be one more bit of magic in the `__` magic methods. Unlike other methods, they're not looked up on the class instances when called implicitly.

It's well documented that they don't get resolved with the `__getattribute__` magic method (and it would be a nice paradox if they did, since `__getattribute__` would have to call itself to resolve its own name). But not checking the instances surprises me.

It's discussed a bit here, under the header "Special Method Lookup":
http://segfaulthunter.github.io/articles/biggestsurprise/

> For instances of new-style classes, all special method lookup that is done implicitely is done in the class struct. Thus changing an instance's `__str__` attribute does not effect the result of str(). Still, explicitely getting the attribute from the instance gives you the method in the instance.

I will be curious to see if anyone else can offer a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

If we for the moment ignore that you are asking about special methods, then your code would look like this:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a_fun = lambda: 1
```

Is written more clearly like this:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._int = 1

    def a_fun(self):
        return self._int
```

The resulting code isn't *exactly* the same, but close enough for it to not make much of a difference. The only difference is that the `_int` name has to be looked up as an attribute.

But if we now change it back to be a special method, it looks like this:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__int__ = lambda: 1
```

vs:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._int = 1

    def __int__(self):
        return self._int
```

And now there is a very big difference: The second variant works, the first one doesn't. This is because special methods is always looked up on the class, not the instance. This is by design.

So instead of trying to be clever, just write what is clear and readable. In Python that tends to work best. ;-)

Comment: `The resulting code isn't exactly the same` ... could you elaborate?

Comment: And I'm not trying to be clever. Don't even get me started on how it sacrifices readability.

Comment: @Mike: I did elaborate: The only difference is that the _int name has to be looked up as an attribute.

Comment: You did. I missed that. Thanks for the response.